# Need to access Google Custom search api through R

Tags: r, api, ssl, google-custom-search

How do I use R to do a Google Custom search? I have the custom search engine id and the api key. I currently try to do this:

```
getURL("https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key=API_KEY&cx=ENGINE_ID&q=searchterm")
```

and I get the following error:

> Error in function (type, msg, asError = TRUE)  :    SSL certificate
>   problem: unable to get local issuer certificate

Though I am able to get the results in json when I do a get request in the browser. Any clue on whats happening?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

httr package worked!!

```
library(httr)
query="https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key=API_KEY&cx=ENGINE_ID&q=SEARCH_TERM"
content(GET(query))
```

Answer (score 3):

set `ssl.verifypeer=TRUE` in `getURL`

```
getURL("https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key=API_KEY&cx=ENGINE_ID&q=searchterm", ssl.verifypeer=TRUE)
```

Comment: It worked for me when I set `ssl.verifypeer" = FALSE`, which seems more logical anyway. The parameter is not mentioned in the help.