# How to search the internet for pages containing specified terms and storing the results in a data table, from within R, using OpenSearch

Tags: r, opensearch

I am setting up a database of certain events that have occurred in the past, and need to search the internet for a number of terms to retrieve as many pages as possible that contain terms related to the happenings i want to document.

First I looked into achieving this using Googles "Custom Search API", after reading this question:
[Need to access Google Custom search api through R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30246787/need-to-access-google-custom-search-api-through-r)
I did manage to get a JSON of search results through the browser, but not through R, so I moved on.

When I saw that the Custom Search API was using OpenSearch, and found the rOpenSearch package for R, I wanted to try going down this path:
http://terradue.github.io/rOpenSearch/

After reading through the documentation, there was only provided examples of searching sites that provide opensearch descriptions. As I need to search as many websites as possible, it seems like I would need an opensearch description for a search engine like Google. But I can't seem to find that anywhere.

Is there any way to search the internet via. R using OpenSearch, and collecting the results in a data table?

If you know of a better solution to my problem, I'd appreciate if you could point me in another direction.

Answer (score 0):

If I read well, you are looking for something called **Web Scraping** via R.

<[See me!](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/an-introduction-to-web-scraping-using-r-40284110c848/)>

Comment: Web Scraping might be part of my task, to extract the text from each result/source found through google, or preferably, OpenSearch. 

To my understanding, you need a webpage as a starting point for web scraping. In my case, i don't know which pages to scrape, as I am interested in all webpages that contain a set of keywords.

Do you know if web scraping would work without a known website as a starting point?